# What causes these ServiceArea artifacts?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, spatial-analyst

I'm building a bus service coverage tool, using ESRI's javascript API with NetworkAnalyst Route and Service Area tools on ArcGIS Server 10.2.1 doing the heavy lifting.

Workflow:

- Identify 2 or more 'stops'
- Route between them, in order
- Generate service areas for each stop

Most of the time this works well, but I'm getting artifacts in the service areas for some stop locations:
[image: ServiceArea artifacts]

The green diamonds are stops.
The grey areas are service areas (returned from the ServiceArea task)
The pink lines are the 'output lines' (returned from the same ServiceArea task)

If I move stops 4 and 5 around, I get different artifacts:
[image: Different artifacts]
(including one for stop 8, which I didn't move!)

If I set `ServiceAreaParameters.overlapPolygons = true`, I get no artifacts:
[image: No artifacts]

Does anyone know what causes these artifacts, and if there's some setting (other than `overlapPolygons = false`, because I explicitly want the result produced by the non-overlapping request) that stops it from happening? Is it just a bug in Server 10.2.1? Has it been fixed in a later version?

```
stRoutePlanner._serviceAreaTask = new ServiceAreaTask(stRoutePlanner._serviceAreaTaskURL);

var saParams = new ServiceAreaParameters();
saParams.facilities = new FeatureSet();

$.each(stRoutePlanner._stopLayer.graphics, function(idx, p) {
    saParams.facilities.features.push(p);
});

saParams.defaultBreaks = [500];
saParams.overlapLines = false;
saParams.overlapPolygons = false;
saParams.doNoLocateOnRestrictedElements = false;
saParams.outSpatialReference = new SpatialReference({ wkid:102100 });
saParams.outputLines = NATypes.OutputLine.TRUE_SHAPE_WITH_MEASURE;
saParams.outputPolygons = NATypes.OutputPolygon.DETAILED;
saParams.useHierarchy = false;
saParams.returnFacilities = false;
saParams.restrictionAttributes = []; 
saParams.restrictUTurns = NATypes.UTurn.NO_BACKTRACK;

stRoutePlanner._serviceAreaTask.solve(saParams, stRoutePlanner.processCoverageResults, tris.errorHandler);
```

Comment: 10.2.1 was not the terminal release of 10.2.x, and has been superceded by 10.3.1, 10.4.1, and 10.5.1 during each of the past three years. This seems like a question to take to Esri Tech Support, but at a minimum, you must upgrade to 10.2.2.